# jpa 2 hibernate setting a lock on EntityManager.find

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, locking, jpa-2.0

I'm doing a few testcases on an hibernate project:

when I call

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
em.find(Foo.class, 1)
```

I get the entity as I expect, but when I invoke:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
em.find(Foo.class, 1, LockModeType.WRITE)
```

I'm getting null. Also, when I make:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Foo foo = em.find(Foo.class, 1)
em.lock(foo, LockModeType.WRITE);
```

I'm getting the object, and it's working as I expect.

EDIT:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="foo")
static class Foo implements Serializable {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String code;
    @Version private Integer version;

    public Foo() {
    }
            ........        
}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-Beta-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you give me a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce. With the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Version private Integer version;
    ...
}
```

The following snippet just works:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Foo foo = em.find(Foo.class, 1, LockModeType.WRITE); 
assertNotNull(foo);
foo.setName("baz");
em.flush();
```

And reads and updates the entity using optimistic locking, with version update:

```
10:21:42.223 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select foo0_.id as id25_0_, foo0_.name as name25_0_, foo0_.version as version25_0_ from Foo foo0_ where foo0_.id=?
10:21:42.225 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 1
10:21:42.229 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning 'bar' as column: name25_0_
10:21:42.230 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - returning '0' as column: version25_0_
10:21:42.246 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update Foo set name=?, version=? where id=? and version=?
10:21:42.248 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'baz' to parameter: 1
10:21:42.249 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 2
10:21:42.249 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '1' to parameter: 3
10:21:42.250 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '0' to parameter: 4
```

Tested with Hibernate 3.5.5-Final.

---

You are **not** using the same version (I mentioned it explicitly because of issues like  [HHH-5032](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5032)). Try with the following dependencies instead (you don't need to specify a dependency on the `hibernate-core` artifact, you'll get it transitively):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I try with the same version, but still having the issue.

Comment: Great, it seems to work now.. but I found another thing (going to edit the post, little small here)

Comment: @Hugo Ok, glad it's solved. Regarding the new problem, this is another question. So please open a new one (the best practice is to not mix topics) and explain why this test is supposed to throw an exception, I don't see why it should.